# Azure: I am stuck trying to create an Ubuntu VM which will be reachable through an existing azure vlan

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, vlan

I am stuck when creating an Ubuntu VM which will be reachable through an existing Azure vlan virtual network

I have tried creating a new VM and in the Networking part, I am only given the option of creating a new v-net, rather than being able to use an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

While creating a new VM, please ensure that the VM is in the same region as the region of the VNet.

Doing this will show you all existing Vnets in that region under Networking tab while selecting Vnets.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I thought that might be it but when trying to create one this morning, I chose the same region as the VNet (in my case, North Europe).
Unfortunately, the VNet I need, which I have double-checked is on North Europe, is not showing in the dropdown.
I have started to create a VM in Default Networking Resource group, in North Europe.
My v-net is in that resource group in North Europe.
However, when I click [Next] in the set up and it shows the Virtual Network dropdown, my existing v-net does not appear.

I am now thoroughly confused.

Many thanks,